# Как в angular 2 расшарить переменные для всех компонентов

Tags: angular2, typescript

Есть АПИ (данные на него передавать не нужно, на сервере живет cookie-сессия)

```
{"login": "test", "ban": 0}
```

И корневой компонент
**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class User {
  login: string;
  ban: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent {

  user: User

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/server/api/userService').subscribe((data: User) => (this.user = data))
  }

}
```

В шаблоне этого компонента я могу увидеть {{ user.login }}. А как сделать так, чтобы эту переменную было видно в шаблоне любого компонента?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону написания UserService, который можно инжектить и хранить там нужную вам информацию, если таких объектов планируется очень много, можно глянуть в сторону Redux и сохранения состояния в store.

Comment: Перенес код в user.service.ts, добавил @Injectable(). Но чуда не произошло, {{ user.login }} везде пустые, обращение к апи не происходит

Comment: Дак нужно заинжектить сервис в компоненты , где ожидается использование  и дёргать {{userservice.user.login}}

Answer (score 1):

Через SharedService вроде будет лучший подход:

```
export class SharedService {
    globVariable:string;
}
```

Но будте осторожны при регистрации, должен быть один экземпляр для всего приложения. Регистрировать как-то так:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [SharedService]);
```